# iPhone Development - Setting UIWebView font

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have to show rich text that i pull from server, so i'm using UIWebView. Now the problem is that i have no control over the font which is used in UIWebView. How can i change the font to use system font (making it consistent with rest of the application)?

I'm doing something like this at the moment:

```
myRichTextView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
myRichTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myRichTextView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
[myRichTextView loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myBaseURL]];
```

Again, need to control the display font. If i can't control the font, please let me know other alternatives to UIWebView.

Thanks

Comment: if you're pulling from a server, what's the string for myString? Wouldn't all the text come from the server?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reference a css style sheet in your HTML document or put the style information into the top of the HTML document itself

Answer (score 103):

It worked when i modified the string like this. Your right chris, it shouldn't make any difference.

```
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                "<head> \n"
                                "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                                "</style> \n"
                                "</head> \n"
                                "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content];
```

Comment: ok thats right. Just another doubt, which HTML-font is equivalent to "SystemFont" in ios? Hope its not a big question to be posted as a new question...

Comment: I keep waiting for Apple to let users change the system font. so I go just a tiny step further. I do a `UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:21];` and instead of hard coding `@"helvetica"` I put in `font.familyName`

Comment: @DBD since iOS9, the `fontName` will be something like `.SFUIText-Regular`, which doesn't work with HTML

Answer (score 15):

I use the following CSS in a web view to do exactly what you are saying.

```
body
{
    font-family:helvetica;
}
```

But yours looks the like it should work as well.  Strange.  Only difference I can see is the font vs font-family, but that *shouldn't* make a difference.

chris.

Comment: Yep this works.  And also if you have a space in the font's name, you need to put it in quotes, such as "helvetica neue", san-serif

Answer (score 11):

System Font

**-apple-system** on iOS 9 & Safari OS X 10

```
font-family: -apple-system;
font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; // iOS 8 compatible
```

Answer (score 10):

[I made a method](https://gist.github.com/rsaunders100/8711151) that wraps some text in a HTML body with the correct style for a given `UIColor` and `UIFont`.  It is based on [Mustafa answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452883/296446).

It is used like this:

```
NSString * htmlString = [MyClass htmlFromBodyString:@"an <b>example</b>"
                                           textFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]
                                          textColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

another easy way that worked for me

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

      NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica; font-size: %i\">%@</span>",
                     (int) font.pointSize,
                     [bodyText stringWithNewLinesAsBRs]];
       [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

just change

`font:helvetica`

to

`font-family:helvetica`

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
body {
        font-family: 'Noteworthy-Bold';
    }
```

This works fine for my about-page (WebView), as the rest of my app also uses Apple's "Noteworthy-Bold".

If you want to use your own font, make use of @font-face and refer to a TTF or EOT file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my easy to use and easy to expand solution with more font settings:

```
                myHTMLLabel = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myX,myY,myWidth,myHeight)];

                myHTMLLabel.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
                myHTMLLabel.scalesPageToFit=NO;

                [myHTMLLabel setOpaque:NO];
                myHTMLLabel.backgroundColor = myBackColor;

                NSString *myHTMLText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>"
                                        "<head><style type='text/css'>"
                                        ".main_text {"
                                        "   display: block;"
                                        "   font-family:[fontName];"
                                        "   text-decoration:none;"
                                        "   font-size:[fontSize]px;"
                                        "   color:[fontColor];"
                                        "   line-height: [fontSize]px;"
                                        "   font-weight:normal;"
                                        "   text-align:[textAlign];"
                                        "}"
                                        "</style></head>"
                                        "<body> <SPAN class='main_text'>[text]</SPAN></body></html>"];

                myHTMLText = [myHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[text]" withString: myText];
                myHTMLText = [myHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[fontName]" withString: myFontName];
                myHTMLText = [myHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[fontSize]" withString: myFontSize];           
                myHTMLText = [myHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[fontColor]" withString: myFontColorHex];
                myHTMLText = [myHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[textAlign]" withString: myFontAlign];


                NSLog(@"*** renderHTMLText --> myHTMLText: %@",myHTMLText);

                [myHTMLLabel loadHTMLString:myHTMLText baseURL:nil];
```