# Setting font in UIWebView for a loaded in rss feed

Tags: xcode, iphone

How would I set the font for an rss feed I am loading into UIWebView?
Right now the rss feed loads in fine but is a default font and size that is undesirable. 
I would like to somehow control that.

I am a super beginner so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need ?
[iPhone Development - Setting UIWebView font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font)