# How to change Custom Font in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, webview

I tried

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768203/how-to-set-custom-font-in-uiwebview)

I loaded m.facebook.com into my UIWebView, which I'd like to change to a custom font. However, the font did not change. I believe the above answer is for static HTML Page.

I'm new to iOS, so a detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is here, which is [Safari CSS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Introduction.html)

You can also try this:

```
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                            "<head> \n"
                            "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                            "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                            "</style> \n"
                            "</head> \n"
                            "<body>%@</body> \n"
                            "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content];
```

Ok, so what we did was basically declared an `NSString`. We call it `myDescriptionHTML`. The  string basically has HTML code/structure that, in a nutshell, changes the body font to helvetica. And the `[NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content]` basically specifies that the font size.
Then:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Now our `UIWebView` is calling the method `loadHTMLString: baseURL:`

The `loadHTMLString:` takes a parameter that has a HTML structure, `myDescriptionHTML` is perfect, we just declared that to load the HTML page with a specific font. `baseURL` parameter will be needed for something like an image, but we won't need that, unless your font is not supported/you created it.

Comment: how can i use that in UIWebView.Please more detail. Please.

Comment: and loadHTMLString is what? sorry for bother you. I am just beginner

Comment: no problem man... i used to be like that too.. ill update the answer with some annotations

Comment: Error showing in content parameter.In content place,which i add that place?

Comment: i fixed [webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
check above if thats what u mean

Comment: besides font size "[NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content];
"  that content. what item i need to add? I don't have variable name content. It's show error. Really thanks you for helping me. :)

Comment: Hi i don't understand what is the meaning of content that beside of Font size. Please