# How to set the font style of WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I am using this line of code to set the font and the size of the text.But this is not working

```
NSString *abc=@"<html><body style=\"font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; color:#000000;\"></body></html>";
    [msgWebView setCustomTextEncodingName:abc];
```

Please let me know how can i set the font style of text in a WebView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Development - Setting UIWebView font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font)

Comment: put the style tag in the 'head' tag and not in the 'body'

Comment: @shannoga..I am now using this but still it is not working..and one more thing to say is that i am not showing any text in the webView,the user will enter text in it and i want that the text entered by user should have this font style..

NSString *abc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
    "<head> \n"
    "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
    "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
    "</style> \n"
    "</head> \n"
    "<body></body> \n"
    "</html>", @"Verdana",[NSNumber numberWithInt:20]];
    [msgWebView setCustomTextEncodingName:abc];

Comment: @NareshSharma yes brother i will :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're approaching it the wrong way. Another way is:

```
[[msgWebView preferences] setDefaultFontSize:12];
[[msgWebView preferences] setStandardFontFamily:@"Verdana"];
```

Comment: @vervious...i dont know who gave you negative vote..but your solution did work very well..thanks for the help.

Comment: This solution does not change the WebView font

Comment: works perfectly (obviously if your html doesn't contain a predefined font/size in the html tags)