# How to keep  2 different fonts within the same UITextField or UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to set 2 different fonts within the same `UITextField` and `UITextView` . How to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that you want to have 2 different fonts within the same textfield? Or are you asking how to change the font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a bit of work - you'll need to use [Core Text](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) and [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.

There are plenty of tutorials and examples, although I'd suggest using someone else's already-made UILabel subclass such as:

[OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

or

[TTAttributedLabel](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmattt%2FTTTAttributedLabel%2F&ei=JY4JUPu6N8Wa2AWU8u22Bw&usg=AFQjCNGwGpeMNaaUvEYpB90EWRxAjE8OLw&cad=rja)

As these usually have some convenience methods to make handling a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with 2 custom textfields overlaying, both backgroundcolor:clearColor, maybe stuffed on an image that represents the background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to handle 2 different fonts within the same UITextField or UITextView. If you want to have different font style you can either set different font style within a UIWebView or use the coreText API.

Here are some links that might help:

1. [iPhone Development - Setting UIWebView font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font)
2. the official doc on core text: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

I know you already picked a valid answer but... don't do it that way... it's not worth it. Use a webview instead and draw everything with html.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder change Text View's Text field to Attributed. In that small editor that appears you can change the font/format/color of the selected text, like in any advanced text editor.