# Multiple fonts inside a single UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a TextField and three buttons which are 40pts above the TextField. These buttons provide the changing of font size of TextField's text when I clicked on any of them for eg first button set font size to 17 second changes it to 20 and third change it to 24. So I add IbAction to all buttons like

```
   - (IBAction)setRegularText:(id)sender {
    self.additionalInfo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

}
```

And according to button. But it will change the previous entered text too. I want the text font to be change only when user selet the option. Previously entered text's font size must not be changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583805/4606601

Comment: What option user can select here?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the attributed string `NSAttributedString`. With text field it is best to have a delegate and implement the method on changing the characters in range. This will handle all the cases even when the user pasts the text from somewhere else.

So the `NSMutableAttributedString` has a method to replace the string in range with a mutable attributed string which is perfect for this method. The new string received by the delegate must simply be converted to the attributed one with a currently set font.

Try something like this:

```
@interface AttributedTextField : NSObject<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIFont *currentFont;

@end

@implementation AttributedTextField

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // ensure having a font
    UIFont *font = self.currentFont;
    if(font == nil) {
        font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    }

    // ensure having a base string
    if(self.attributedString == nil) {
        self.attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    }

    // append the new string
    [self.attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:range withAttributedString:[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}]];

    textField.attributedText = self.attributedString; // assign the new text which is attributed

    return NO; // return false as we are overriding the text
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

set the tag of every button as the font size that button should change.
i-e

```
self.button1.tag = 17;
self.button2.tag = 20;
self.button3.tag = 24;
```

and use the tag as font size.
i-e

```
- (IBAction)setRegularText:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.additionalInfo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:sender.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set different text size in textfield like this way:

```
- (void)setFontString:(NSString *)setString setFontSize: (double) fontSize {

    self.txtAnswer.text = @"";
    self.txtAnswer.text = setString;
    self.txtAnswer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
}

- (IBAction)btn1Tap:(id)sender {

    [self setFontString:@"Good Morning" setFontSize:20.0f];
}

- (IBAction)btn2Tap:(id)sender {

    [self setFontString:@"Good Afternoon" setFontSize:15.0f];
}

- (IBAction)btn3Tap:(id)sender {

    [self setFontString:@"Good Evening" setFontSize:10.0f];
}
```