# Fixed width for an word (countdown timer 3:45) in UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to show countdown timer in UILabel but when I am updating the timer next sentence/ word position is getting changed. Complete sentence after timer is moving left, right. 
[image]
I want to fix the width for timer(4:47) so that only timer value should update without changing position of any other word. Any Idea will be help full to fix this. I can't use three labels because text is multiline.

Here is the code I am using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {[weak self] timer in
        self?.updateText()
        if let time = self?.reservedTimeInSeconds, time < 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            self?.reservedTimeInSeconds = 300
        }
    }
}

func updateText() {
    let minutes: Int = self.reservedTimeInSeconds / 60
    let seconds: Int = self.reservedTimeInSeconds % 60
    let timer = String(format: "%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)

    self.textLabel.text = "Price valid for: \(timer). All prices inclusive of 3% gst."

    self.reservedTimeInSeconds -= 1
}
```

I tried using attributed string but no luck, this code somewhat working but when I trying to set custom font and font size its breaking.

```
func updateText() {
    let minutes: Int = self.reservedTimeInSeconds / 60
    let seconds: Int = self.reservedTimeInSeconds % 60
    let timer = String(format: "%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    let html = "<div>%@ <div style=\"color: %@;text-align: center;display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;\">%@</div>. %@</div>"
    let htmlFilledString = String(format: html, "Price valid for: ", "green", timer, "All price inclusive of 3% gst. All price inclusive of 3% gst")
    self.textLabel.attributedText = htmlFilledString.html2AttributedString

    self.reservedTimeInSeconds -= 1
}


extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583581/how-to-keep-2-different-fonts-within-the-same-uitextfield-or-uitextview

Comment: @kmithi Does my answer work guy?

Comment: @trungduc Yah some what useful, just had to change y position so that if first text also become multiline then timer comes at right place.  Problem is my app support multiple language and in some language string are really hudge.

Comment: @kmithi I have updated my answer with solution for multiple line label. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use three labels, I think you can use 2 labels to resolve this problem ;).

- Calculate width and height of text before count down timer. In this case, it's "Price valid for ". You can use below extension to do it.

  ```
  extension String {
    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
      let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font];
      let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes);
      return size.width
    }

    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
      let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
      let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)
      return boundingBox.height
    }
  }
  ```
- Create one more `UILabel` (`countDownLabel`) with same font as `mainLabel`, give it green `textColor`.
- Make `coundDownLabel` overlap `mainLabel`.
- Instead of setting

  ```
  mainLabel.text = "Price valid for 4:36. All prices are inclusive of 9234% GST.";
  ```

  Use

  ```
  mainLabel.text = "Price valid for          . All prices are inclusive of 9234% GST.";
  ```
- Finally, give `countDown` a right leading and top constraints.

  ```
  let displayedText = "Price valid valid valid valid for _counDownTimer_. All prices are inclusive of 9234% GST.";
  let labelWidth : CGFloat = 200;

  // Add main label
  let textLabel = UILabel.init();
  textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
  textLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray;
  textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  textLabel.text = displayedText.replacingOccurrences(of: "_counDownTimer_", with: "         ");
  self.view.addSubview(textLabel);

  // Update constraints for |textLabel|
  textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true;
  textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true;
  textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true;

  // Add timer label
  let countDownLabel = UILabel.init();
  countDownLabel.textColor = UIColor.green;
  countDownLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
  self.view.addSubview(countDownLabel);

  // Calculate position and update constraints of |countDownLabel|
  let timerTextRange = displayedText.range(of: "_counDownTimer_");
  let textBeforeTimer = displayedText.substring(to: (timerTextRange?.lowerBound)!);
  let textWidth = textBeforeTimer.widthOfString(usingFont: textLabel.font);
  let textHeight = textBeforeTimer.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: labelWidth, font: textLabel.font);

  var leadingConstant = textWidth;
  let topConstant = textHeight - textLabel.font.lineHeight;

  let indexOfCountDownLine = NSInteger(textHeight / textLabel.font.lineHeight) - 1;

  if indexOfCountDownLine > 0 {
    leadingConstant = leadingConstant - CGFloat(indexOfCountDownLine) * labelWidth;
  }

  countDownLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.topAnchor, constant: topConstant).isActive = true;
  countDownLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: leadingConstant).isActive = true;
  ```

**Result**

[image: enter link description here]

For more detail, you can take a look at my demo repo [here](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/countdown-label).