# WKWebView with custom font type and color

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, wkwebview

I want to load html string with custom font family and text color at WKWebView , I tried to embed this CSS at HTML but it doesn't work :( .

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %d;}\n"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                   "</html>", @"DINNextLTW23Regular", self.fontSize,@"Text"];
```

Comment: Check answer's here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449773/iphone-development-setting-uiwebview-font)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you can create a css file then add your fonts and styles inside this file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONT_FAMILY';
    src: local('FONT_FAMILY'),url('FONT_FILE_NAME.otf') format('opentype');
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'FONT_FAMILY';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

And load html string with css file

```
NSString *css = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<head>"
                        "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"YOUR_CSS_FILE.css\">"
                        "</head>"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body>"
                        "<h1>%@</h1>"
                        @"</body>", @"YOUR_TEXT"];

[_wkWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", css, content]
                   baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_CSS_FILE" ofType:@"css"]]];
```

You can change the style name h1 with yours

Comment: after hours of search, you made my day bro !!

Answer (score 0):

The `font-family` should be the system font family. Otherwise, you must import the custom font file to your project.

Comment: In the `xxx.plist` file, you need add:
   ` <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
 <string>Your_Font_File_Name.TTF</string>
</array>`